# Struts 2.3 form with multiple submit tags with action attribute

Tags: forms, jsp, struts2, dmi

This is something quite simple which worked perfectly with Struts 2.1.x. But we recently upgraded to 2.3.15.2 and it broke. Basically we have a form (actually, many forms) with multiple submits:

```
<s:form>
 <s:submit action="save"  />
 <s:submit action="resetPassword"  />
</s:form>
```

If I stick the action in the  tag all is well. But if instead it is in the  tag, I get a 404 error. And it's the same action!

I've been debugging and discovered that when you use the "action" attribute in the  tag, the generated html is:

```
<input type="submit" name="action:save">
<input type="submit" name="action:resetPassword">
```

Supposedly Struts should take this "action" prefix and say "A-ha! This is an action!" and execute it. And it more or less does this. Or at least tries to. What I've discovered is that at a very low level, the DefaultActionMapper.handleSpecialParameters() method goes through all the parameters and tries to create a ParameterAction for each one, and if it's not null, it is executed. Most of the parameters produce a "null" ParameterAction, but not "action:".

In the docs I found this about ParameterAction:

```
Defines a parameter action prefix.  This is executed when the configured prefix key is
matched in a parameter name, allowing the implementation to manipulate the action mapping 
accordingly.  For example, if the "action:foo" parameter name was found, and a 
ParameterAction implementation was registered to handle the "action" prefix, the execute 
method would be called, allowing the implementation to set the "method" value on the 
ActionMapping
```

So what it does is set the mapping's result to a new ServletDispatcherResult with the name of the Action:

```
mapping.setResult(new ServletDispatcherResult(actionName));
```

On the other hand, when the action is specified in the s:form tag, the mapping's result is null.

So that when *finally* we get to Dispatcher.serviceAction():

```
if (mapping.getResult() != null) {
 Result result = mapping.getResult();
 result.execute(proxy.getInvocation());
} else {
 proxy.execute();
}
```

So when the action is specified in the  tag, proxy.execute() is called, which just calls the Action/method itself. Which is what *should* happen! But when the action is specified in the  tag, since the mapping has a result, the proxy's invocation is passed to result.execute(), which calls ServletDispatcherResult ... and in the end, I get a 404.

This seems like a whole lot of work just to get multiple submit buttons with action attributes working. Is this a known issue for Struts 2.3? Do I need to implement a ParameterAction for the "action" prefix as stated in the docs?

**EDIT**

Ok, known bug, opened just a few days ago. In the meantime I can either downgrade to 2.3.15.1 or use the "method" attribute rather than the "action" attribute.

Hopefully it will be fixed soon ...

Comment: 2.3.15.1 has 2 known security vulnerabilities - the details have not been fully published - but 2.3.15.2 is fundamentally broken. More and more people are coming across this fact and you'd have thought that they would warn people from downloading it and tell people just to use 2.3.15.1 in the meantime.

Answer (score 5):

this is b/c in struts2.3.16.

#### Disables support for action: prefix

by default `struts.mapper.action.prefix.enabled = false`

set

```
<constant name="struts.mapper.action.prefix.enabled" value="true"/>
```

in struts.xml

Internal Changes of struts2-core 2.3.16

The action: and method: prefixes are be by default excluded and changed order to first check excludeParams and then acceptedParams in ParametersInterceptor

Answer (score 2):

This is supposed to be in the process of being fixed for 2.3.15.3.

The specific jira is:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-4204